# poor quality with Adobe Flash. How do the pros do it?

Tags: flash, adobe, cs4

I'm thinking of developing an application with Adobe Flash CS4 but I'm having some serious quality issues when importing material from Adobe Photoshop CS4 and Adobe Fireworks CS4.

When I import the material as a bitmap, the quality is better (then importing as movieclip) but not good enough.

I was just wondering, how do the pro's do it? All the big companies, organizations ect ect

Do they use some other software?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I usually export bitmap graphics as PNG files from Photoshop and then import those into the Flash CS IDE, rather than importing PSD files, that is. Also, if you haven't noticed, you can set individual compression settings on each bitmap in the library in your FLA, and set to uncompressed if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you importing your PSD's directly? You might be better off saving your images for web then importing them into Flash like normal images. Anyway, try these two suggestions out:

1. Make sure when placing your images onto the stage, that their dimension and locations are whole numbers. Having them with a X and Y position of 0.5 will cause them to look blurred.
2. Open your library panel, find the image you imported and right-click on it. Select properties. Set the compression to Lossless (PNG/GIF). Be careful with this though, using lots of images with this compression will result in much larger file sizes.

Comment: so thats how they do it, haha. There was me thinking they use a completely different program, thats probably only available on MAC... Thanks a bunch mate.